# Best way to handle PDO query exceptions

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have a basic question on the best practices way to use try/ catch blocks with PDO queries in php. Say I have a query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(1, $param);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sub_sth->fetchColumn();
```

What is the best practice method for encapsulating this in a try block and catching an exception in either the sql syntax or execution?

N.B. the PDO connection itself ($dbh) already has exception handling.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 2):

It is usually helpful to make your error handling as atomic as possible. Encapsulate each of the statements that may throw an exception in a separate try/catch block.

In this case, the statements that may throw exceptions are:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

and

```
$sth->execute();
```

This granularity allows you to troubleshoot problems with precision, as opposed to large try/catch blocks which allow you only to find the *section* of code that caused a problem.

See [Ralph Shindler's article](http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3) for an in-depth treatment of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the configuration PDO uses emulated prepared statements. Hence the `->prepare` call itself will not trigger an exception. That's why you should wrap both `prepare` and `->execute` in the same `try{}` block.

In my experience with real prepared queries it's uncommon to see exceptions only on the `->execute` call anyway. It's most typically the SQL query that's wrong. However that is a development problem, not a runtime issue, so catching exceptions for the prepare seems less logical.

Anyway, my advise would be to wrap both unless you can really come up with a way to recover in two different ways from the problem (which IMHO is unlikely for the SQL `->prepare` and syntax errors.)

Comment: Thanks for the good info so far. This did prove useful in my case:http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#99518